# Postgres/SQL Join and Update

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Joins are the one thing I could never get my head around, ie, which type to use and how they actually work. I need to write a query and I know I will need a join for it.

The database is postgres.

Basic table set up is like this (some details redacted)

```
rates (
rates_id Primary Key, Auto Increment
state String, can either be 'current' or 'history'
)

rates_records (
rates_records_id Primary key, auto increment
rates_id = integer
column_1,
column_2
)
```

Every `rates_records` entry has `rates_id` set to a value that exists in the `rates` table

I want to update every `rates_records` row and modify the `column_1` and `column_2` data where the associated `rates` `state = 'current'`

How would I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to Stefan's answer.

```
update rates_records 
   set column_1 = 'foo', 
       column_2 = 'bar'
from rates 
  where rates.rates_id = rates_records.rates_id
    and rates.state = 'current';
```

More details and examples are in the manul: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Which format you prefer is basically a matter of taste. I don't believe one is better or faster than the other (Stefan's answer being standard SQL so it's portable across DBMS).

Comment: Actually, besides being shorter, this should be substantially faster than the `IN` variant, where you also have a redundant join operation. It's the way to go.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: are you sure the IN variant would be faster? Postgres is not bad at optimizing those things.

Comment: `IN` is *slower*, not faster. While `IN` is generally the slowest option, the redundant `JOIN` is the more important factor here.

Answer (score 0):

```
update rates_records set column_1 = 'this', column_2 = 'that'
where rates_records_id 
in (select rates_records_id from rates_records rr 
join rates r on rr.rates_id = r.rates_id where state = 'current')
```